# How to load two json file?

Tags: android, json, realm

I got an error when I try to load two files.
My question is how to load two json file into realm.

The following is loading json file:

```
private void loadJsonFromStream() throws IOException {

    InputStream stream = getAssets().open("school.json");

    realm.beginTransaction();
    try {
        realm.createAllFromJson(School.class, stream);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Remember to cancel the transaction if anything goes wrong.
        realm.cancelTransaction();
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            stream.close();


        }
    }

}
```

The following is loading the setting Setting file.

```
private void loadJsonSettingFromStream() throws IOException {

    InputStream streamSetting = getAssets().open("setting.json");

    realm.beginTransaction();
    try {

        realm.createAllFromJson(Setting.class, streamSetting);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Remember to cancel the transaction if anything goes wrong.
        realm.cancelTransaction();
    } finally {
        if (streamSetting != null) {
            streamSetting.close();


        }
    }
```

Comment: Showing your error may allow others to give you better assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Expected a boolean but was NUMBER"

I guess you use 0 and 1 to express boolean value instead of "true" and "false" strings in the json files.

Change the stucture of the pojo or the json. If those aren't options, you can easily write a custom parser to map integers to boolean.